# Jquery Mobile Datebox Slidebox

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

When I was using the DateBox1 I had this code to use the slidebox only for months and days:

```
<input name="calendarDaily" id="calendarDaily" type="date" data-role="datebox" 
data-options='{"mode": "slidebox", "fieldsOrderOverride":["m","d"], "noButton": true, "centerWindow":true, "useInlineHideInput":true}' />
```

But with Datebox2 this options doesn't work and in this web http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/fullopt.html there is no reference to the options I want!

How can I with DateBox2 to do the same with the old Datebox1?

Thank you!

Comment: @J.T.Sage where are they now?

Answer (score 0):

Check `internationalization / localization` section for more settings.

There's a `slideFieldOrder` setting, i.e. field order for slide mode, e.g. `['y', 'm', 'd']`

Comment: I tried "<input name="calendarDaily" id="calendarDaily" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "slidebox", "slideFieldOrder":["m","d"] }' />" but there isn't difference. EDIT: Because it's for language file! I have two slidebox's: one with day and month and the other with only month to display.. this field doesn't work.